# Changing Nested Classes in Derived Class c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having the following issue.

I have a class **Base** with a nested class **A**. I want to make a third class **Derived** outside of **Base** which inherits it. However I need to add several member variables, as well as, change some of the methods of the nested class (namely constructors to initialize them) but couldn't find out how.

One way I managed to get it to somewhat work was to declare a new nested class inside **Derived** which inherits from **A** but this confuses me as of what actually happens. I am left with the impression that I actually then have two nested classes which is not what I want.

```
class Base
{
    class A
    {
        //memberVariables
    public:
        A()
        {
            //initialize memberVariables
        }
    }
}

class Derived : public Base
{
    class B : public A
    {
        //newMemberVariables
    public:
        B() : A()
        {
            //initialize newMemberVariables
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do it or should I stick to that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Above, do you actually mean to say `newMemberVariables` are members of Derived (and not B)...but you expect B's constructor to be initializing them?  In which case you are correct that it's not going to work.  Derived should be initializing its own member variables.  But generally, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Edited. Was a mistake on my side, indeed. They are supposed to be in B. What I am asking is if it possible to expand A in Derived instead of creating a new class.

Comment: There's one and only one way `Derived` can change stuff inherited from `Base`, namely, *override virtual functions defined in Base*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With C++ it is not possible to 'expand' a class declaration, whether the class is nested or not. So to your question in the comments:

> What I am asking is if it possible to expand A in Derived instead of
>   creating a new class

The answer is no. You are correct that your solution, which defines class `B` as a derived class of `Base::A`, is in fact creating another nested class.